# Python closure: Why changing dictionary in closure is allowed while changing numbers isn't?

Tags: python-3.x, closures, local

this code works well when I try to change dictionary in closure

```
def a():
    x = {'a':'b'}
    def b():
        x['a'] = 'd'
        print(x)
    return b
>>> b = a()
>>> b()
{'a':'d'}
```

output is meeting my expectation. but why the code below doesn't work?

```
def m():
x = 1
def n():
    x += 1
    print(x)
return n
>>> n = m()
>>> n()
```

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment**

Honestly, I've known that we can use `nonlocal x` statement to solve this problem
But can anybody explain the reason more deeply for me? **what the difference** between a dictionary and a number
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a great [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) specifically on this.

In short, when you modify a dictionary, or any [mutable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/) object, you modify the same object, so you don't re-assign the variable. In case of an integer, since it's immutable, by doing a `+=` you create a new object and put it into `x`. Since x is now defined inside the inner function, but you're trying to bring data from the outer function, you have an issue.

You can check if it's the same object using `id()`.